# Get Rails3 to Load Different View

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working on a Rails3 app that has a Pages controller, and two pages: pages#main and pages#status.  The main page has a link which, when clicked, goes to status.  The user already has profile information, and if part of that profile information is not present, I want status to redirect to main.  I'm getting a mysterious double-redirect though, that I can't solve.  Here's the pages controller:

```
def main
  @current_user = current_user
end

def status
  @current_user = current_user
  if @current_user.address.blank?
    redirect_to :action => "main" and return
  end
end
```

Everything works swimmingly as long as the condition isn't met, but as soon as it is, I get the error:

> Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".

Indeed, redirect_to is called twice (same line, according to the trace; not sure why). I'm wondering whether it is a routes problem.  Here is routes.rb:

```
match '/main', :to => 'pages#main'
match '/status', :to => 'pages#status'
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the development log:

```
Started GET "/status" for 127.0.0.1 at Wed Nov 03 21:28:15 -0700 2010
  Processing by PagesController#status as HTML
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" = 3) LIMIT 1
Before redirect
Before redirect
Redirected to 
Redirected to 
Completed   in 32ms

AbstractController::DoubleRenderError (Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".):
app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:15:in `status'
app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:15:in `status'
```

Trying to solve the problem, I've added two debugging lines to the status method, in the hopes that it will provide some clue:

```
  logger.debug "Before redirect"
  redirect_to :action => "main" and return
  logger.debug "After redirect"
```

So, the "Before redirect" lines are hit before we get to "Redirected to". Then "Redirected to" appears twice with no target.  Incidentally, this happens with or without "and return" on the redirect line.  I'm really not sure what's going on.

Also, interestingly, I added a debug line to the main method.  It is never triggered.

Comment: Could you solve this problem? I face more or less the same...

Answer (score 0):

Rav, can you paste the development log for this request?  Specifically, does the first request for /status result in a redirect to /main, or does it fail with the above error?

Specifically, look in log/development.log for the most recent request block or blocks.

Comment: I have pasted in the logs, and some more info above.  Thanks for getting back to me.

Comment: I think the redirect_to is not working.  Instead of specifying the action, try "redirect_to(main_url) and return"

Comment: "redirected to" blank is what leads me to believe your redirect_to is not working.

Comment: I put a "debugger" line right before the redirect and I got ... two "redirected to" lines printed to the log as soon as I did this.  No idea what's going on.  I think I'm going to just avoid the problem altogether: make it so the original link is created based on the conditional information as opposed to sending it to status and requiring a redirect.  It is a mystery though.  Thanks for your suggestions.